# Why do none of my plugins work for Apache Cordova?

Tags: cordova-plugins

I am using cordova to load plugins into my app.  Here is the simplified reproduceable issue:

cordova create foo
cordova plugin add pluginname --save
cordova platform add android --save
cordova build android --verbose

I can run this app using phonegap and see it on my phone.  The app reports deviceready as the basic starter app is supposed to.  All looks great so far.

If I look in the plugin folder I can see my plugin there.  In this case my plugin is called bluetoothle.

I edit the index.js file at a location that fires after the deviceready occurs and add "alert ( typeof (bluetoothle));"

I expect that when the alert fires it should report "object".  It does not do this.  It reports "undefined".

I have tried this with several other plugins and I always get the same result.  So it would seem that no matter what plugin I install I cannot access any of the functions within the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same Problem. But I'm using the Phonegap CLI. And the following plugin: https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle

I add the plugin using the command:

`$ phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetoothle`

I've added platform android and ios.

So in the plugins folder there is the cordova-plugin-bluetoothle folder most probably being a valid plugin packet.
Also in the plugins folder there is the android.json and ios.json file containing the section:

```
"cordova-plugin-bluetoothle": {
    "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.phonegap.helloworld"
},
```

in plaforms/android there is the android.json file containing:

```
{
    "xml": "<feature name=\"BluetoothLePlugin\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"com.randdusing.bluetoothle.BluetoothLePlugin\" /></feature>",
    "count": 1
},
```

in platforms/ios there is the ios.json file containing:

```
{
    "xml": "<feature name=\"BluetoothLePlugin\"><param name=\"ios-package\" value=\"BluetoothLePlugin\" /></feature>",
    "count": 1
},
```

I've targeted Android SDK API 23. As the readme tells...

As I have just modified the hello-world example to call bluetoothle initialize on after the deviceready event has fired.

**So where could the problem be so that the bluetoothle variable is not defined in the index.js code, when the device is ready?**

So here the complete code of index.js:

```
var bluetoothle;

var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        console.log("platform: "  + device.platform);

        if(bluetoothle) {
            console.log("bluetooth is not defined!");    
        } else {
            console.log("bluetooth is not defined!");    
        }

        console.log("yhea managed to initialize Bluetooth LE!");
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

And the complete code of index.html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
    <!-- Good default declaration:
    * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
    * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
    * Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
        * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
    * Create your own at http://cspisawesome.com
    -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" /> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sooo,

The Issue I had before I just "worked around" by using a different Plugin for my Bluetooth Low Energy stuff.

Later I ran into the same Problem again with another Plugin.

And then I finally got the picture where it all makes sense:

I was mainly using the Phonegap Developer App to test on-the-fly.
The Phonegap Developer App comes bundled  with all the Core Plugins and some others.

!! Those plugins which are not bundled already, will never be accessible for your Phonegap Developer App for testing !!

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-new-unbundled
```

Will not make it available to the App. Only download and prebuild the files for a potential real build.

To make this work in the Phonegap Developer App you would need to build your own Phonegap Developer App adding the Plugins you need.

Otherwise your Plugins are only available in a real build.